# Need to remove and sort key numbers and color items from dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, key, removeall

I have a Dictionary like:

```
var map = new Dictionary<int, ColorType>();
```

where ColorType is an enum { Red, Yellow, White }

It is paired with an array of Numbers like:

```
var lstNumbers = Enumerable
            .Range(1, 100).OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
            .ToArray();
```

I need to do the following:

1. Remove all even numbers that are Red
2. Remove all odd numbers that are Yellow
3. Remove all numbers divisible by 3 that are White
4. Sort list ascending based on number and then color (Red

Is the an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is there any observation about the inefficiency about your code? What is wrong if it works?

Comment: I don't understand what `lstNumbers` has to do with anything in this question. Are some of those operations against **both** the list and dictionary?

Comment: You will not be able to get more efficient than the sorting method used in step 4. Sorting is a well known efficiency and there is no known improvement on the fastest approach. Steps 1-3 will all be O(n) and are therefore irrelevant to the efficiency of the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove multiple items matching a predicate from a c# Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469202/best-way-to-remove-multiple-items-matching-a-predicate-from-a-c-sharp-dictionary)

Comment: I thought about using this but am not sure if this is the right approach.

    toRemove = lstNumbers.Array
                                    .Select(x =>
                                    new KeyValuePair<int, ColorType>((int)x.lstNumbers, x.ColorType))
                                    .ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first 3:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, ColorType> entry in map.ToList()) {

    if (entry.Key % 2 == 0 && entry.Value == ColorType.Red) { // Even and Red
        map.Remove(entry.Key);
    }

    if (entry.Key % 2 == 1 && entry.Value == ColorType.Yellow) { // Odd and Yellow
        map.Remove(entry.Key);
    }

    if (entry.Key % 3 == 0 && entry.Value == ColorType.White) { // Divisible by 3 and White
        map.Remove(entry.Key);
    }
}
```

As for sorting your dictionary, the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-dictionary-by-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: You can't iterate and modify the collection at the same time.

Comment: Yeah my bad, didn't test it before posting. Updated

Comment: Would it be map.ToArray() since I'm using an array or does it matter?

Comment: Also I am getting a KeyNotFound Exception in my display portion.

    foreach (var num in lstNumbers)
                Console.WriteLine($"{num}, {map[num]}");

            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Some of the entries in the dictionary have been removed (in the previous loop) so when you do `map[num]` on the list of numbers in lstNumbers you will get a KeyNotFound Exception

Comment: I'm not sure why my comments don't format to the codeblock format. I'm sure I'm not entering it correctly. I was just trying to indent it by 4 spaces like you do in posting but it desn't work the same way. Still learning the Forum functionalities.

Comment: You need to either loop through the dictionary to print the values or check if the value exists in the dictionary before printing.

Comment: @JusteasyStackAttacka In comments, wrap code blocks in a backtick (`\` `) character.

Comment: `foreach(var entry in map) { Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}, {entry.Value}"); }`

Comment: @Rufus oddly enough the captions to comments informed me of the mini-Markdown formatting right after asking. lol But Thanks Anyways!

Comment: @ L.B Thanks for your help This has been racking my brain for awhile!
@Rufus That is the correct print for my values as well Thank you!

Comment: I found a good Sorting method but then realized I did not have the specific details of what to sort by included. 

So far I have:

   'List<KeyValuePair<int, ColorType>> myList = map.ToList();

            myList.Sort(
                delegate (KeyValuePair<int, ColorType> pair1,
                KeyValuePair<int, ColorType> pair2)
                {
                    return pair1.Value.CompareTo(pair2.Value);
                }
            );'

I need to sort by: 

1: Sort list numbers ascending and by colors Red < Yellow < White

How can I apply these specifications?

Comment: `Would it be map.ToArray() since I'm using an array or does it matter?` `ToArray` is _slightly_ slower than `ToList` @JusteasyStackAttacka.